# Make Intellisense list member variables within a member function without typing 'this'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

While implementing a C++ class-member function, is it possible (using a keyboard shortcut) to make Intellisense list only the member variables without having to type 'this->'?

The coding style I am using marks member variables with a _ postfix, so I cannot filter member variables by typing m_ or _.

Comment: Don't confuse "Intellisense" with "intelligence"... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible (using a keyboard shortcut) to make Intellisense list
>   only the member variables without having to type 'this->'?

Sorry but the answer is negative. As far as I know this behavior is not supported in VS itself currently. We can't show the list of member variables by using a keyboard shortcut. Go `Tools menu => Options => Text Editor => C/C++ => Advanced` , then you can get the Intellisense settings about C++ there.

[image]

But the settings don't provide the feature that show member list with keyboard shortcut.         To let Intellisense **only** display member variables, you need to type `this->`. Or you have to type the **keywords** to filter the list.

> marks member variables with a _ postfix, so I cannot filter member
>   variables by typing m_ or _.

What's the format of your member variables, something like `_variable` or `variable_`, you can type the `va` to get a filtered list like this:

[image]

**In addition:**
If you have unique needs for this feature, feel free to post your feature request for VS in [DeveloperCommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). If it gets enough points, this feature would be considered by the team. Also, you can have a look at the extensions in [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/),you can check if there exists one extension to achieve the behavior you want. Hope it helps:)